# TypeScript y angular. Tipado de un array de objetos en angular

Tags: array, angular, typescript, javascript-objeto, componentes

Soy principiante; así que no se molesten por lo básico de mi pregunta.
Al ir aprendiendo typescript, al momento de asignar el tipo a un array de objetos lo hacía de la siguiente manera:

```
let titulos:object[]=[
  {titulo: 'el resplandor'},
  {titulo: 'soy yo'}
]
```

Funciona bien. Pero cuando quiero hacer algo parecido dentro de un componente de angular

```
export class TitulosComponent implements OnInit {
  titulos:object[];
  constructor() {
    this.titulos= [
      {titulo: "hola"},
      {titulo: "chau"},
      {titulo: "anda rápido"},
      {titulo: "anda volando"}
    ]
   }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Y me tira error al querer acceder a la propiedad del objeto mediante una directiva *ngFor:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let titulo of titulos">{{titulo.titulo}}</li>
</ul>
```

Me dice

> error TS2339: Property 'titulo' does not exist on type 'object'.

Pero si no le asigno el tipo a la propiedad no da ningún error. O sea así:

```
export class TitulosComponent implements OnInit {
  titulos;
  constructor() {
    this.titulos= [
      {titulo: "hola"},
      {titulo: "chau"},
      {titulo: "anda rápido'"},
      {titulo: "anda volando'"}
    ]
   }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Soy autodidacta y no puedo entender por qué sucede esto. ¿Alguien me lo puede explicar? Muchas gracias.

Comment: También tira error ( error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.) Solo funciona si no lo inicializo como en el segundo ejemplo. Asi que lo hice funcionar, pero no entiendo por qué no funciona con el tipado normal (titulo: object[ ])

Comment: Es un error de compilación o en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: es d compilación

Comment: Si me lo imaginaba, te respondí de todos modos. Espero haber sido claro. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript es una mezcla rara entre javascript y un lenguaje fuertemente tipado.

En un lenguaje fuertemente tipado el Object es (generalmente) una clase de la cual el resto de los objetos descienden, es la clase padre de todo.

Pero esta clase no tiene atributos y por eso te arroja error. Lo que intentas hacer es convertir un Object en otra cosa que no es, esto se puede hacer en Javascript pero no en Typescript

¿Por qué funciona si le quitas el tipo?

Es decir si lo dejas así:

```
export class TitulosComponent implements OnInit {
  titulos;
//.....
```

Porque esto es lo mismo que colocar:

```
  titulos:any;
```

El tipo 'any' es la respuesta de Typescript para ser compatible con javascript. Un any puede ser cualquier cosa y es lo mismo que el Object en javascript y quizás ahí viene la confusión.

Por último, lo normal en un lenguaje fuertemente tipado es crear una Clase o una Interface que defina tus objetos

```
interface Titulo{
 titulo:string;
}
```

```
export class TitulosComponent implements OnInit {
  titulos:Titulo[];
//.....
```

Comment: En general usar `any`es la salida fácil, pero es una mala práctica. No es lo mismo que usar object.